# ¿Como validar si un campo de texto es numerico en Java?

Tags: java, jtextfield

¿Como validar si un campo de texto es numerico en Java? Tengo validaciones para textfields que reciben Strings, y me avisa cuando está vacío.

```
boolean Valida(){
    if(txtRFC.getText().equals("")){
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Llene todos los campos");
        return true;
    } 
        return false;
}//Validaciones
```

¿Como lo hago de esta forma, pero limitando el campo a enteros (Integers)?

Answer (score 2):

Para validar si no tiene valor puedes usar el método **[.isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty())**

```
if(txtRFC.getText().isEmpty()){
...
..
```

> [.isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty())  Devuelve true si y solo si length () es 0.

Puedes combinar también el método `.trim()` para eliminar posibles espacios en blanco.

```
if(txtRFC.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
...
..
```

> ¿Como lo hago de esta forma, pero para cuando el textfield tenga que
>   recibir Integers?

Ahora para validar si el valor es numérico, puedes crear un método para verificar si el valor que introduces es numérico.

```
public static boolean esNumerico(String valor){     
    try{
        if(valor!= null){
            Integer.parseInt(valor);
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
         return false; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Puedes usarlo de esta forma (con `.trim()` para evitar espacios en blanco).

```
if(!esNumerico(txtRFC.getText().trim()){
   //Valor no es numérico.
}else{
  //Valor ES numérico.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para validar si un campo es númerico puedes intentar convertir el valor en un `int` con `parseInt` y devolver true o false según el resultado. Este método también daría error en caso de dejar el `textField` vacío, aunque sería más correcto verificar campos vacíos con `isEmpty()`.

```
public boolean checkInteger() {
 try { 
    Integer.parseInt(txtRFC.getText()); 
 } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
    return false; 
 }
 return true;
}
```