# Crash android java

Tags: java, android

Estoy realizando una calculadora de números primos en android, y todo va bien excepto que si dejo en blanco el input, crashea automáticamente al pulsar el botón "calcular". He probado a meterlo en un try catch pero no se como controlar las excepciones, ni si esa es la mejor manera de solucionarlo.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText input;
    TextView output;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.positionInput);
        output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answerText);

        output.setText(" ");
    }

    public int getPrimo(){
        int primo = 2;
        int counter = 2;
        return primo;
    }

    public void calcular(View view) {
        String pos = input.getText().toString();

        int position = parseInt(pos);

        if (position >= 0) {
            output.setText("El primo número " + position + " es el " + getPrimo());
        } 
        else {
            output.setText("Por favor, introduce una posición positiva");
    }
}
```

PD: si por casualidad veis algún fallo en nomenclaturas o por el estilo decidmelo porfa

Comment: [Esto](https://aprenderaprogramar.com/foros/index.php?topic=1235.0) es lo que quieres

Comment: Vale ya he encontrado solución, muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes usar un mètodo para determinar si el valor es nùmerico : https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/171187/95 o simplemente validar si marca error que obtenga un valor default, en este caso 0

Answer (score 1):

Las excepciones no deben usarse para validaciones. Puedes comprobar si el valor de pos es válido antes de convertirlo a entero:

```
public void calcular(View view) {
    String pos = input.getText().toString();

    // si alguno de los caracteres no es un dígito, mostrar mensaje y regresar
    if(!pos.matches("^[0-9]+$")){
        //mostrar mensaje

        return;
    }

    int position = parseInt(pos);

    if (position >= 0) {
        output.setText("El primo número " + position + " es el " + getPrimo());
    } else {
        output.setText("Por favor, introduce una posición positiva");
    }
```

Comment: Me da varios errores debido a que empleo la API 16 de android, pero lo apunto y gracias

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> "todo va bien excepto que si dejo en blanco el input, crashea
>   automáticamente al pulsar el botón "calcular"

El error se produce al convertir el valor dentro del `EditText` a entero en esta linea:

```
int position = parseInt(pos);
```

Debes validar si el valor no es un entero, evitar realizar la conversiòn usando `parseInt()` de la siguiente forma:

```
public void calcular(View view) {
    String pos = input.getText().toString();

   //Validaciòn
   int position = 0;
   try{
      if(pos!= null){
         position = Integer.parseInt(pos);
      }
   }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
     //Error, el valor de posicion sera 0. 
   }

    if (position >= 0) {
        output.setText("El primo número " + position + " es el " + getPrimo());
    } 
    else {
        output.setText("Por favor, introduce una posición positiva");
    }
}
```

si ocurre un error el valor de position serà 0.