# Situación rara para detener la ejecución de un método

Tags: c#

Buen día a todos. Saben si es posible que exista una forma de detener la ejecución de un método que me retorna un valor y en base a una condición seguir la ejecución o no. El uso de **return;** no funciona en este caso.

```
public string MetodoDemo(bool val)
{
    if(val){
       //Aquí no funciona el return; a menos que sea un metodo void
       return;
    }
    int resultado = 10 + 10;
    if(resultado == 20){
      return "A";
    } else {
     return "B";
    }
}
```

**Actualizo**

Solo debo romper la ejecución sin retornar nada así se produzca algún error.

Comment: y si haces return null?

Comment: @gbianchi no debo retornar nada solo romper la ejecución. ¿No es posible?

Comment: Y no. Si tu metodo no es void debe o retornar algo o tirar una excepcion. Mi pregunta seria, que va a hacer quien llamo a este metodo si no devuleve nada? Acepta tomar una excepcion?

Comment: @gbianchi Parece ser que sí, es lo que desean o bien retorna algo o se produce la excepción. Pero no comprendo la razón, como no tengo acceso a esa "lógica", solo me asignaron esa tarea. Pero si ese el caso tendré que dialogar con la persona para que me muestre esa lógica del código o comentar que no es posible

Comment: Ok. Las dos respuestas que te dieron es la forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacer uso de excepciones:

```
public string MetodoDemo(bool val)
{
    if(val){
       throw new System.ArgumentException("val no es válido")
    }
    int resultado = 10 + 10;
    if(resultado == 20){
      return "A";
    } else {
     return "B";
    }
}
```

Y podrías utilizarlo con un try-catch:

```
static void Main()
{
   try
   {
       MetodoDemo(true);
   }
   catch(System.ArgumentException ae)
   {
       // Aqui pones lo que se deberia de hacer cuando suceda
       // Logs, mensajes, etc.
   }

   // Aquí continuas con los demás procesos
}
```

Incluso podrías crear tus propias excepciones para identificar de mejor manera el por qué se lanzó.

Sin embargo, te recomiendo seguir las mejores prácticas, recomendadas por Microsoft, al trabajar con excepciones:

[Mejores prácticas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions)

Answer (score 3):

El uso de `return;`  no aplica cuando tu método define un valor de retorno, en este caso forzosamente tendrás que retornar un valor de tipo `string`:

```
public string MetodoDemo(bool val)
{  ...
   ...
}
```

como opción podrías retornar un `string` vació y de esta forma validar que no retorno ningún valor.

```
public string MetodoDemo(bool val)
{
    if(val){
       return ""; //retorna cadena vacía.
    }
    int resultado = 10 + 10;
    if(resultado == 20){
      return "A";
    } else {
     return "B";
    }
}
```

También podrías optar por retornar un valor null como comenta @gbianchi

```
public string MetodoDemo(bool val)
{
    if(val){
       return null; //retorna valor null.
    }
    int resultado = 10 + 10;
    if(resultado == 20){
      return "A";
    } else {
     return "B";
    }
}
```

pero en todos los casos debes retornar un valor ya que tu método no es `void`.

Comment: Jorge puede hacer return null...

Comment: muy cierto, gracias actualicé la respuesta! @gbianchi

Comment: @Jorgesys para este caso se decidió el uso de excepciones. Saludos!

Comment: El validar a partir de provocar un error no es algo recomendable, se supone que lo que debemos evitar es la generación de excepciones no esperar se provoque una para validar :-| , saludos @JeffersonCuji

Comment: En esta ocasión no puedo objetar al que decidió que se haga así ( ._.)

Comment: Hola @JeffersonCuji no fuiste tu? jejejeje, coméntale que es mejor no esperar se provoque un error para validar, hay pocos casos en los que si aplica con en este https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/171187/95 en el cual de alguna forma tienes que validar si una cadena es numérica, si se provoca un NumberFormatException indicaría que no es una cadena de números, pero son pocos los casos :-)